# How to add the task bar to both displays?

Tags: 20.04, dock

G'day everyone!

I've got a joint display with my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.2 and I want to know how I can add the dock to both displays. I know how to move it from one screen to the other in the display settings but I can't figure out how to put it on both.

If anyone could give me some tips that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the setting as I was writing this question. The dock settings are located in the appearance settings under the window theme. There is a "Show on" menu. choose all.